# Proper way to reuse a std::istringstream object

Tags: c++

I have a class that needs to do a lot of input handling. I'd like to use `std::istringstream`.

I have the following function, the purpose is to read input and replace the current `m_buffer` with the user input.

```
void myClass::readInput(){
    
    std::string s;
    std::getline(std::cin, s);
    m_buffer.str(s);

}
```

where `std::istringstream m_buffer;` is a member variable of my class.

However, this only works on the first call for the following:

```
readLine();
m_buffer >> some_integer;
```

and does not work on subsequent calls (does not read anything out of `m_buffer` into `some_integer`), so I am left wondering when it is correct to include `std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');` and if that is the issue.

Here are a few different solutions I've tried:

```
// using the << operator instead of .str(s) -> compiler error (this is confusing to me)
// I had thought this was the proper way to do it
m_buffer << s;

// having readLine() return an istringstream and initializing a new one -> works
std::istringstream buffer = readLine();

// having readLine() return an istringstream and re-assigning an existing -> doesn't work (also confusing, given the above worked)
m_buffer = readLine();
```

My issue here is I would like to reuse the same `std::istringstream` for all my inputs instead of re-declaring a new one every time. Is there any way I can do this?

I tried using `std::stringstream` instead, but I have the same issue of not being able to reuse it without incorrect results.

---

Update:

the correct function is

```
void myClass::readInput(){

    std::string s;
    std::getline(std::cin, s);
    m_buffer = std::istringstream();
    m_buffer.str(s);

}
```

Could anyone please answer why

```
m_buffer << s;
```

does not work?

Comment: You could always do `m_buffer = std::istringstream();`

Comment: You need to reset the stream state as well, not only make it use a new string. The easiest solution is as shown by @CaptainObvlious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the easiest ways is to just assign a new `istringstream` to `m_buffer` like so...

```
m_buffer = std::istringstream();
```

This will create a new instance of `istringstream` and "re-initialize" the existing stream in `m_buffer` with it by using move semantics to *move* the entire (fresh) state of the new `istringstream` into `m_buffer`.

To return the buffer from `readLine` you can rely on move semantics to help you out there too.

```
std::istringstream myClass::readLine()
{
    std::string s;
    std::getline(std::cin, s);
    return std::istringstream(s);
}
```

Comment: As a followup, why does this work but I'm unable to do `m_buffer = readLine()` where `readLine()` returns a `std::istringstream` ?